# Create a unique dictionary and add auto increasing integer values

Tags: c#, linq

How can I add a unique number to each of the distinct keys?

In the end I want a "collection" of the distinct keys but each key should have also a value which is e.g. the current_index_of_collection + 1

```
elements.SelectMany(p => p.Properties.Keys).Distinct();
```

sample output:

```
Key value
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   4
```

Comment: I'm guessing you already have the keys stored somewhere?

Comment: the keys are in each element properties.keys collection. I need to add increasing integer values which serve as database ids (unique/autoinc)

Comment: If you want a unique, auto increment database id you better use the database's built in mechanism for auto increment. Otherwise you might risk getting wrong values (especially if you are running the code in different threads or simply multiple times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `Select((value, index) => ...)`?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var dictionary = elements
  .SelectMany(p => p.Properties.Keys)
  .Distinct()
  .Select((key, index) => new {
     key = key,
     value = index + 1, 
   })
  .ToDictionary(item => item.key, item => item.value);
```

Or

```
var array = elements
  .SelectMany(p => p.Properties.Keys)
  .Distinct()
  .Select((key, index) => new KeyValuePair<MyKeyType, int>(key, index + 1))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: hm I even used the index overload of Select was somehow confused. Thanks I like your solution most as it has everything in it with the ToDictionary()

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Select` overload which has an index field:

```
string[][] elements = new string[][] { new string[] { "a", "b", "a" } };
var elementsWithIndex = elements.SelectMany(p => p)
                                .Distinct()
                                .Select((p, i) => new { Key = p, Value = i + 1 });
```

Or in your code:

```
var elementsWithIndex = elements.SelectMany(p => p.Properties.Keys)
                                .Distinct()
                                .Select((p, i) => new { Key = p, Value = i + 1 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this.

```
    List<string> keys = new List<string>();
    keys.Add("a");
    keys.Add("b");
    keys.Add("c");
    keys.Add("d");
    keys.Add("e");
    keys.Add("f");
    keys.Add("g");


 var fields = keys.Distinct().Select ((t,val)=> new { Key= t, Value= (val + 1)});
```